# Do seo questions loosely involving code belong here or on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

[How bad is it to use display: none in CSS?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css)

Seems like it could be appropriate to both. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The general consensus thus far is that we're going to have a bit of overlap between SO and SF, possibly a little with SU. Just because a question would be equally appropriate on any of the other trilogy sites does not mean it's not welcome here.

As long as the question is in the *context* of what *is* on topic here, and not "99% programming 1% SEO", it should be perfectly fine. In other words, finding some way to *make* a question about SEO just because it did not get answers on SO might be frowned upon by some members of the community. However, if the ultimate (and original) goal of the question has something to do with running a website, it's fine.

After we get out of beta, it is very likely that we will be able to migrate questions to and from SO and SF, but I can't be quoted on that.

Answer (score 2):

I think that question belongs here.  Questions about SEO code fall into these categories to me:

1. How does this code affect my SEO
2. How do I make this code work better for SEO purposes
3. This code doesn't work, how do I fix it

1 and 2 belong on Pro Webmasters.  3 Belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context of the question. That person is asking about SEO implications of using `display:none;` so I would say it totally belongs here.

If they were asking about the technical aspect of the CSS style (for example, how does it affect DOM rendering) then that would be for doctype, so on and so forth.